# Ways to modify chapter titles in KOMA-class

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I am using KOMA-class. Let's say I want my chapter titles to look like this:

[image]

However the closest thing I can get is this:

[image]

The code I used is this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %providing dummy text
\usepackage{adforn} %providing ornaments

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt,beforeskip=2\baselineskip]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\adforn{36}\enskip\thechapter.\ }

\begin{document}

    \kant[1]

    \chapter{An Interesting Chapter Title}

    \kant[2]

    \begin{center}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \scshape\large \adforn{36}\enskip 1. An Interesting Chapter Title\enskip\adforn{36}
        \\
        \rule{2em}{1pt}
    \end{center}

    \noindent\kant[3]


\end{document}
```

Things I already modified:

1. The font for the chapter title.
2. Centering.
3. Not starting a new page.
4. Vertical space before the title.

But I don't know how to add characters or even a new line after the actual chapter title is printed.

I would also like to know about further ways than those I already used, KOMA-classes provide to change chapter titles (whether it makes sense to use them is another thing).

**Edit:** As schtandard remarked, one has to make a decision how the title should look when it takes several lines. So let's see for example if we can get the following to work:

[image]

My code (which is certainly terrible):

```
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \scshape\large
        \adforn{36}\hspace{-1em}
        \parbox{11cm}{\centering 1. An Interesting Chapter Title Which is Way Too Long to Fit in One Line}
        \hspace{-1em}\adforn{36}
        \\[\baselineskip]
        \rule{2em}{1pt}
    \end{center}
```

Note that here the box has a fixed length of `11cm` which is fine for taking the picture, but in practice, one should be able to specify a *maximal width* so that the box becomes shorter if the title is short.

Comment: Do you want to change the section or chapter titles?

Comment: @Johannes_B In my current document, it's the chapter titles, but I guess it will be rather similar.

Comment: Do you only have chapter headings that fit in one line or do some of them break into several lines? If so, where should the ornaments go in that case?

Comment: @schtandard Good question, I did not think about that one yet. To make it more difficult, let's say the two lines of the chapter title should be put in a box with a defined maximal width and the ornaments should be left and right to that box, vertically centered. (Just trying to see what is possible here.)

Comment: Then how do you want your titles to appear in the ToC?

Comment: @remco Just ordinary font, I guess. But the ToC entries can be formatted independently using `\chapterentryformat`, I think.

Comment: But you run into problems if you have to modify your chapter title to add the leaf like I tried to do: the leaf will appear in the ToC...

Comment: Another question: how you you want the chapter number to be treated? Just as part of the title, in which case a full second line (and perhaps a 3rd) will be flush left with the number, or do you want it hanging?

Comment: @remco I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the difference. But I think my third sample image looks quite good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `style=section` for chapters then you have to redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to change the layout for chapter titles:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %providing dummy text
\usepackage{adforn} %providing ornaments

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt,beforeskip=-2\baselineskip]{chapter}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
      \raggedchapter
      \adforn{36}\enskip
      \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-6em\relax}
        \raggedchapter#3#4%
      \end{varwidth}%
      \enskip\adforn{36}%
      \par\nobreak
      \strut\rule{2em}{1pt}%
      \par
    }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\chapter{An Interesting Chapter Title}
\kant[2]
\chapter{An Interesting Chapter Title Which is Way Too Long to Fit in One Line}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think I really have to start reading also the Advanced part of the KOMA-script documentation. I will have a closer look at `\chapterlinesformat`.  (I only changed the style of the chapters so as to avoid blank pages.)

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the indent in the very first paragraph of each chapter?

Comment: Use `beforeskip=-2\baselineskip` (note the `-`). I have changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %providing dummy text
\usepackage{adforn} %providing ornaments

\makeatletter
    % \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=2\baselineskip]{chapter} % <-- this seems too little
    \setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\scshape}
    \renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter.\ }
    \patchcmd\scr@startchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}

    \newbox\@chapter@heading@testbox
    \renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
        \savebox\@chapter@heading@testbox{#2#3}%
        \ifdim\wd\@chapter@heading@testbox>\dimexpr\linewidth-6em\relax
            \raggedchapter
            \adforn{36}\hskip 1em%
            \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-6em}{%
                \raggedchapter
                #2#3
            }%
            \hskip 1em\adforn{36}
            \@@par
        \else
            \parbox{\linewidth}{%
                \raggedchapter%
                \adforn{36}\hskip 1em%
                {\let\@@par\relax
                    #2#3%
                }%
                \hskip 1em\adforn{36}%
            }%
            \@@par
        \fi
        \raggedchapter\strut\rule{2em}{.4pt}\par%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\chapter{An Interesting Chapter Title}

\kant[2]

\chapter{An Interesting Chapter Title Which is Way Too Long to Fit in One Line}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: the output of the code above]

What is happening here?

- Chapter is *not* redeclared to be of type `section`.
- The pagebreaks are instead avoided by removing the appropriate code from `\scr@startchapger` using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`.
- We now use `\chapterlinesformat` to format the chapter heading (`#2` contains the formatted chapter number, `#3` the formatted chapter title).
- We first check if the heading is longer than one line and then typeset it accordingly.
- `#3` contains a `\@@par`. Since we want to have the second ornament on the same line as the title, we need to deactivate it before typesetting in the case of a single line heading.
- The `\strut` on the line with the `\rule` makes sure it has the correct distance from the heading in the case of multiple lines.

Please note that as a consequence of centering your headings, the second (and subsequent) lines of the chapter title may flow below the chapter number.

Comment: I am still trying to understand your code. For now I only realized that I can make the ornaments look misplaced if I call my chapter like this: `\chapter{AnInterestingChapterTitleWhich isWayTooLongtoFitinOneLine}` Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @JohnDorian what do you mean? For me, the ornaments appear in the exact same spot as in the image above (for chapter 2).

Comment: I mean that they are very far away from the title and don't always have a distance of, say 1em, to the title, as they have in one-line titles.

Comment: That's right. I do not know if it is possible to determine the width of the text inside the `\parbox` (maybe somebody else does), so I decided to just place the ornaments `1em` *from the parbox* (which should usually be fine, I think).

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but one thing that worked for me for single line titles was adding

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{chapter}{1}%
    \chapter*{\chapterformat #1\enskip\adforn{36}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter.\ #1}
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip}%
    \begin{center}
        \rule{2em}{1pt}
    \end{center}
}
```

after '\renewcommand{\chapterformat}...'. And then of course use \mychapter instead of \chapter.
But I feel there must be a better way... (adding the formatting in a "\renewcommand{chapterlinesformat}" did not have any effect for me)

From what I've found, packages that allow adapting headers are usually limited to selecting fonts and font styles, they do not provide for modification of the chapter title *contents*, which is what you need here for the second leaf.